# QtDBus linkage error

Tags: qt, visual-c++, dbus, unresolved-external, qtdbus

I built Qt on Windows with WinDBus. Qt itself built OK, but QDbus examples build fails with message

```
moc_car_adaptor_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external 
symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const 
QDBusAbstractAdaptor::staticMetaObject"
(?staticMetaObject@QDBusAbstractAdaptor@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

Folder `E:\qt\4.6.4\msvc2008\lib` contains QtDBus4.dll QtDBus4.lib QtDBusd4.dll and QtDBusd4.lib. All contains `'staticMetaObject@QDBusAbstractAdaptor@@2UQMetaObject@@B'` string.

How to fix it?

Beforehand thankful, Ilya.

**UPD:**
All .PRO files are from DBus examples, I have not changed anything. For example:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Aug 28 19:50:14 2006
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG += qdbus

# Input
# DBUS_ADAPTORS += car.xml
HEADERS += car.h car_adaptor_p.h
SOURCES += car.cpp main.cpp car_adaptor.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/dbus/remotecontrolledcar/car
sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES *.pro *.xml
sources.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/dbus/remotecontrolledcar/car
INSTALLS += target sources

symbian: include($$QT_SOURCE_TREE/examples/symbianpkgrules.pri)
```

**UPD2:**

Command line that QtCreator produces:

```
... moc.exe and cl.exe calls...
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189
-DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
-DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008
\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008\include" -I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008\include
\QtDBus" -I"..\car" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"." 
-I"..\..\..\..\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" 
-Fodebug\ @C:\DOCUME~1\resu\LOCALS~1\Temp\moc_car_adaptor_p.obj.432.2453.jom
moc_car_adaptor_p.cpp

link /LIBPATH:"e:\qt\4.6.4\msvc2008\lib" /NOLOGO /DEBUG /MANIFEST 
/MANIFESTFILE:"debug\car.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS 
/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' 
version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' 
processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:debug\car.exe @C:\DOCUME~1\resu\LOCALS~1
\Temp\car.exe.432.3734.jom
```

Options I built Qt with:

```
configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2008 -shared  -debug-and-release -dbus -dbus-linked 
-qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-psql -no-qt3support -qt-zlib -qt-gif -qt-libpng -qt-libmng 
-qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -openssl-linked -confirm-license -opensource -phonon -phonon-
backend -nomake demos -nomake examples OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32MD -llibeay32MD" 
-I "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include" -I "C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.4\include" 
-I E:\qt\4.6.4\msvc2008\src\dbus" -I E:\qt\4.6.4\msvc2008\src\dbus\dbus" 
-L "C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.4\lib" -L "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static" 
-l ws2_32 -l gdi32 -l user32 -l crypt32 -l advapi32
```

Comment: What does the .pro file look like?

Comment: I've added .PRO file. It is as it was in DBus examples

Comment: And what is the command line used to compile? Is it linking to libQtDBus libs?

Comment: @LucaCarlon Thanks for your answers! I've added command lines. I work on Windows, there is no **lib**QtDBus, only QtDBus.lib and QtDBus.dll. lib files are propperly listed in makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `qdbusmacros.h`:

```cpp
#if defined(QDBUS_MAKEDLL)
# define QDBUS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#elif defined(QT_SHARED)
# define QDBUS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#else
# define QDBUS_EXPORT
#endif
```

`QT_SHARED` was not declared in application, and `QDBUS_EXPORT` becames nothing.

Adding

```
CONFIG += QT_SHARED
```

solved the problem.

Note: in Qt 4.8.4 all works fine (previously I used 4.6.4)